# Add array of String arrays to firebase in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class Person shown below:

```
class Person {
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var username: String
//var profileImage: UIImage
var imageURL: String
var phoneNum: String



init(firstName: String,  lastName: String, username: String, imageURL: String, phoneNum: String) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.username = username
    //self.profileImage = profileImage
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    self.phoneNum = phoneNum
}
```

}

I then attempt to add [Person] to firebase, similar to as follows:

```
databaseRef.setValue("people": [Person])
```

Debugger then spits out the following error:

```
Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
```

I believe that I am working within the firebase constraints. Doesn't class Person inherit from NSArray, since it is nothing more than an Array of String Arrays?

If not, would I have to add each element of the [Person] array separately? Something like:

```
databaseRef.setValue(["firstName": [firstName],
                     ["lastName": [lastName]...)
```

assuming [firstName] & [lastName] are of type String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken basic concepts. Inheritance is about sharing basic characteristic of the object to its heir (or subclass in case os Swift). Real-world example: Rabbit is Heir of Mammal, Mammal heir of Animal. Cage full of rabbits is definitely not a heir of neither Animal, nor Rabbit. But perhaps heir of Furniture.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

As for you code, you are right, you have to store them per value.

Comment: Thank you. Goes to show fundamentals can come back and bite you if you're not paying attention!